# Why is my StarCraft folder 6.79GB?

Tags: starcraft

I was looking through my smaller HDD because, for some reason, it just became almost completely full without having a lot of stuff on it and saw that my StarCraft folder was 6.79GB. I'm not talking about StarCraft II or StarCraft Remastered. It's the free version of the original StarCraft: Brood War that Blizzard put on their website. I can launch it from the Battle.net client and it was downloading updates a while back.

So, why would it take up almost 7GB of HDD space? Did it just download StarCraft Remastered waiting for me to buy it or was the Battle.net client integration some amazingly big update?

Comment: Isn't it possible to look in the folder and see what, exactly, is in there?

Comment: The Data folder is 6GB and it only has `.idx` files and strangely large data files. I checked the patches folder to see if there are old leftover files that just hog space and it's completely empty. I can't enable HD Graphics in the options menu and the game looks and behaves the same as it did almost 20 years ago.

Comment: If it has an HD graphics option but its disabled then I suspect they replaced the original StarCraft with StartCraft Remastered version but disabled the enhanced features if you haven't bought new version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the original StarCraft and StarCraft Remastered are the same game using the same engine. The [1.20 patch](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/17616683188) to StarCraft added all the new high definition content, which would account for almost all of the 6.79GB install, but the [1.20.1 patch notes](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/17616781549) indicates that HD is support is only available for "players with Remastered":

> #### Bug Fixes
>
> - The HDs are available on start up for players with Remastered (one
>   exception; see Known Issues)
>   ...

Rather than having to support two separate versions of the original StarCraft or abandon the SD version that they're now giving away for free, it appears Blizzard has chosen to make them same game. The process of upgrading the original StarCraft engine actually appears to have begun when it was made free back in April, when the first [patch](https://starcraft.com/en-gb/articles/20674424) to the game in just over 8 years was released.

Comment: Well, I guess there's no need keeping it for nostalgia alone then.